# what's the equivalent of `cv2.resizeWindow` in google.colab.patches?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm trying to set the size of cv window/plot on google colab.

Google colab provides `cv2_imshow` as a replacement for cv2.imshow() for use in Jupyter notebooks.

[image]

With opencv, I can set the size of window using this code

```
cv2.resizeWindow('image', 600,600)
```

what's the equivalent of `cv2.resizeWindow` in google.colab.patches?

Comment: There is no equivalent. cv2.imshow opens a new window - Colab has no way of handling new "windows". Take a look at [the actual code for google.colab.patches](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/blob/master/google/colab/patches/__init__.py). Maybe resize the image with opencv? Or another library?

Comment: I just re-read your question. I think you want to be working with a [matplotlib axes object](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using
im1=cv2.resize(image, (100, 100))
and then displayed cv2_imshow(im1)

So basically here the "image" is your image that you want to visualize larger. You can always increase the size (change 100* 100 to something greater)